# Як перекласти "family-size", "compact", "subcompact"?

Tags: переклад, from-english

Як перекласти українською типи автівок *family-size*, *compact*, *subcompact*? Більше цікавлять вживані, а не словникові версії і якщо хтось має гарні ідеї українських новотворів до цих понять - буду вдячна.  Якщо ж існують словники з подібною сучасною термінологією - підкажіть, будь ласка - я не знайшла.

Наприклад, про family-size, я маю здогадку, що це автівка сімейного(чи краще - родинного) типу, а про інші два терміни пів/напівкомпактна і компактна відповідно, але я вірю, що ці слова в українській можуть мати, а може вже навіть мають кращі відповідники.

Я не є водійкою, але в колах практичного вжитку ці слова могли вже набути україномовних відповідників і 'жити новим життям'. 
Можливо ці терміни колись були гарно перекладені для дубляжу і хтось чув їх в кіно(мені, на жаль не траплялося).

Чи таке не варто перекладати і компактний/напівкомпактний - це найліпше, що тут варто вжити?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Класи *compact* і *subcompact* знаходимо в [американській класифікації автівок від EPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_size_class#EPA):

[image]

(Табличку взято [тут](https://www.fueleconomy.gov/feg/info.shtml#size-class) - питання *"How are vehicle size classes defined?"*)

Ці класи слід перекладати як *компактний* та *субкомпактний*. Приклади вживання:

> Новий [компактний](http://mmr.net.ua/new-cars/80101) хетчбек Skoda отримає ім’я Scala, повідомила прес-служба чеського бренду.
>
> Завдяки зручним спортивним сидінням салон [компактного](https://www.nissan.ua/vehicles/new-vehicles/juke.html) кросовера Nissan JUKE ідеально підходить для комфортного водіння.
>
> Renault Captur отримав титул найкращого [субкомпактного](https://www.renault.ua/discover-renault/renault-in-ukraine/news/captur-best-subcompact-crossover.html) кросовера 2018 року в національній премії «Авто Лідер 2018».
>
> Hyundai Motor оприлюднила назву нового [субкомпактного](https://edem-auto.hyundai.com.ua/hyundai-venue-premiere-2019) кросовера, цільовою аудиторією якого стануть міські підприємці.

Класу "family-size" я не знайшла, однак у [класифікації EuroNCAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_size_class#EuroNCAP) є *small family car* та *large family car*.

Їх [перекладають](https://auto.24tv.ua/euroncap_nazvala_naibezpechnishi_avtmoobili_2018_roku_n9457) як *малий сімейний автомобіль* та *великий сімейний автомобіль* відповідно:

> Рейтинг складено для автомобілів у класах "Великий паркетник", "Великий сімейний автомобіль", "Малий сімейний автомобіль" та "Гібрид та електрокар".

Також слово *малий* тут можна [замінити](https://techno.znaj.ua/212231-top-bezpechnih-avtomobiliv-2018-roku-video-krash-testiv) на *невеликий*:

> Кращим у категорії "невеликий сімейний автомобіль" став Mercedes-Benz A-Class.

Табличка "[Класифікація легкових автомобілів](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%96%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F_%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%96%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B2)" на Вікіпедії допоможе порівняти автівки за різними класифікаціями.

Comment: Поправив форматування. Текст, що заключений у `backticks`, призначений для програмного коду. Програми-читачі екрану (screen readers) читають його по окремій літері, як абревіатуру, і тому на мовних сайтах його не варто використовувати. У нас є [стаття на Meta](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/43/8), вона містить багато корисної інформації, хоча, можливо, потребує допрацювання.

Comment: @bytebuster зрозуміло) Тепер сама бачу, що курсивом послуговуватись краще.